# Find my error. Evaluate limit of $\ln(x)-x$ as $x$ approaches positive infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Please refer to the image. I tried to evaluate the function and it is contrary to my checks. Also, I applied L'Hopital.  Please find what makes my solution wrong, and suggest a way to get the answer. Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply L'Hospitals rule  to compute$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln x-x}x}{\frac1x}$$because this is *not* indeterminate. In fact, the limit of the numerator is $-1$, whereas the limit of the denominator is $+\infty$.

You can do it like this: if $f(x)=\ln x-x$, then $f'(x)=\frac1x-1$. So, $f'(x)<-\frac12$ if $x$ is large enough. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Sir i could not arrive at your answer. My numerator after differentiation is (1-lnx)/x^2 and denominator is -1/x^2. .

Comment: @tighten You are right. My mistake. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Btw, i am no math major so be patient with me. A glance at this image from the net( https://image.slidesharecdn.com/lhopitalsrule-110308163926-phpapp02/95/l-hopitals-rule-2-728.jpg?cb=1299602426) gave me the impression it can be done right away. Thanks

Comment: @tighten Please note that it is stated at the third item: “Used to evaluate limits of *indeterminate* forms” (italics added). Yours was not indeterminate.

Comment: Yes. I guess i can apply it when 0/0 and inf/inf or otherwise if i have the other forms i must be able to transform it to the former 2.

Comment: @tighten If its not $\frac00$ or $\frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$, then it is an indeterminate form and therefore you can comput the limit directly.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x$ out:
$$L=\lim_\limits{x\to+\infty} \left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x}-1 \right) \cdot x=-1 \cdot (+\infty)=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You did not apply L'Hospitals rule correctly. You should rather substitute $x = \mathrm{e}^{u}$ the limit will be $$\lim_{u \to \infty}\left[u-\mathrm{e}^{u} \right].$$

The function $u-\mathrm{e}^{u}$ is continuous, hence all sequences with $u_n \to \infty$ should give the same result. pick $u_n = n$ and use induction that $\mathrm{e}^{n}>n^2$ for $n>n_0$.

Comment: In what way did I not apply it correctly?

Comment: You didn't differentiate the terms correctly, see José's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in computing $((\ln x-x)/x)'/ (1/x)'.$ You should get $1-\ln x, $ not $\ln x -1.$ There are 2 logic errors: (i) As the denominator $1/x\to 0,$ l'Hopital will not apply if the numerator $(\ln x -x)/x$ does not  $\to 0$, which is something you haven't addressed. (ii). l'Hopital's rule $\lim f/g=\lim f'/g'$ does not apply  unless the limit is a real number. Review the statement of it in full.

l'Hopital's rule is only one of many ways to find a  limit and it is has considerable restrictions.

By the Binomial theorem, if $2\leq n\in \mathbb N$ then $$2^n=(1+1)^n=1+\binom {n}{1}+\binom {n}{2}+...>\binom {n}{2}=(n^2-n)/2.$$ So if $2\leq n \in \mathbb N$ and $2^n<x\leq 2^{n+1}$ then $$\ln x -x\leq (n+1)\ln 2 -x<(n+1)\ln 2- 2^n<(n+1)\ln 2-(n^2-n)/2.$$

We can get a stronger result with this method: If $2\leq n\in \mathbb N$ and $2^n<x\leq 2^{n+1}$ then $\frac {\ln x}{x}<\frac {(n+1)\ln 2}{(n^2-n)/2}...$ So $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {\ln x}{x}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply l’Hôpital unless you know that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x-x}{x}=0
$$
and it would be hard to prove it, because the limit is $-1$.

A different strategy is to consider the substitution $x=1/t$ that transforms the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\ln\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t}\right)
=\lim_{t\to0^+}-\left(\ln t+\frac{1}{t}\right)
=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t\ln t+1}{-t}
$$
Now it should be known that $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln t=0$, so we can conclude the limit is $-\infty$, because the numerator has limit $1$ and the denominator approaches $0$ by negative values.

If you don't know that $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln t=0$, this is a case where l‘Hôpital *can* be used (for the $\infty/\infty$ form):
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln t=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln t}{1/t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1/t}{-1/t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}-t=0
$$